# Lua: error loading module file not found

Tags: linux, lua, shared-libraries, embedded-linux, fastcgi

I'm trying to set up Lighttpd + lua + fastcgi to run web interface on an embedded MIPS board. But the important part here, I guess is Lua.
When trying to run /usr/local/bin/wsapi.fcgi (which is lua script) I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/lua: error loading module 'lfcgi' from file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/lfcgi.so':
    File not found
    stack traceback:
    [C]: ?
    [C]: in function 'require'
    /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/wsapi/fastcgi.lua:9: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    /usr/local/bin/wsapi.fcgi:9: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
```

Which is really strange, because ls shows that file is there and all permissions are ok:

```
# ls -l /usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/lfcgi.so
-rwxr-xr-x    1 0        0           21152 /usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/lfcgi.so
```

And which is more frustrating, if I actually remove the file, lua shows a different error, which means that first error wasn't really caused by lua unable to locate file properly.
So I'm a bit lost here, looks like the error message is misleading and problem isn't really the file being not found, but what...

P.S. The error comes from file wsapi/fastcgi.lua, from line 9 which looks like this:

```
local lfcgi = require"lfcgi"
```

- maybe there is something wrong with require syntax? I'm no expert in lua so I can't tell.

Comment: can you post the output of `ldd /usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/lfcgi.so` please?

Comment: @Ctx This is embedded platform and I'm very restricted to size, so unfortunately I have no development tools there, including ldd. But I guess It may be the time to install it, because it's not the first time I need it.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I figured it out. It turned out to be a missing dependency, as @Ctx suggested.

```
readelf -d lfcgi.so | grep NEEDED
```

shows that it needs **libfcgi.so.0** which is a symlink to libfcgi.so and I only have the last one, not the symlink.
After creating the symlink it is working now (actually it comes with another error, but it is a different story :P).

By the way - the error message is really confusing - it looks like the file lfcgi.so is missing, when in fact it is one of its dependencies that is causing the problem.